# Noun or Adjective for someone who is good in managing resources and/or money

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, epithet-requests

I am looking to describe someone who is good at keeping track of hir resource use and goods usage behaviour. This can be either for monetary currencies, but also for food, material or other commodities. 
Ideas that I had so far are the following, but I am not fully satisfied:

- Resourcefulness (too cognitive)
- Thriftiness (too mean)
- Frugality (too practical)
- Proneness to Saving (too inaccurate)
- Parsimony (too greedy)

EDIT:

After getting the first suggestions, it seems worthwhile to add that the term will be used with a mainstream audience, and therefore should not be too complicated or too nuanced. (And I am aware that this is quite ironic, looking at the extent of nuance that I am aiming for...)

Comment: "careful" with money?  did you try a thesaurus?

Answer (score 4):

You can say that they **husband** their recources: "Use (resources) economically" ([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/husband)).

Unfortunately, it's a bit archaic, so you don't get the full range of words to go with it.  You can say that they display **good husbandry** ([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/husbandry)), but saying they're a "good husband" doesn't work, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Plus one, best so far

Comment: As much as I like it semantically, we might get ourselves in PC-trouble, looking at gender-sensitivities (that I fully understand).

Answer (score 1):

You could say that they exercise ***[prudent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prudent)*** resource management, or that they manage their resources with ***[prudence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prudent)***.

> #### Prudent
>
> 1. Practical and careful in providing for the future
> 2. Exercising good judgment or common sense

CED, as found at thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

You could say that such a person was *unwasteful*.

Answer (score 0):

en·tre·pre·neur
ˌäntrəprəˈnər/
noun
a person who organizes and operates a business or businesses, taking on greater than normal financial risks in order to do so.
synonyms:   businessman/businesswoman, enterpriser, speculator, tycoon, magnate, mogul; More

con·ser·va·tor
kənˈsərvədər,kənˈsərvəˌtôr,ˈkänsərˌvādər/
noun
noun: conservator; plural noun: conservators
a person responsible for the repair and preservation of works of art, buildings, or other things of cultural or environmental interest.
a guardian or protector

cus·to·di·an
kəsˈtōdēən/Submit
noun
noun: custodian; plural noun: custodians
a person who has responsibility for or looks after something.
"the custodians of pension and insurance funds"

Answer (score 0):

**economical** (*adj.*):

(of a person or lifestyle) careful not to waste money or resources

> '*He was economical in all areas of life*.'

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/economical)